# Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Armor 8G glitch

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I and my friend just bought two `Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Armor` and sometimes the screen becomes noisy as the [video](https://g.redd.it/rln4l43me5s11.gif?fm=mp4&mp4-fragmented=false&s=8e7d3e315abf80fc682814ef93519b5e) for both of us. We have the same PC and monitor.

This happens when I leave the PC for a while without doing anything and restarting the monitor fixes the problem.

I thought the problem is from the monitor but I have been in contact with MSI and they said the problem related to my graphics card.

anyone knows what the problem is this? and do I need to replace the graphics card or it's just a problem with cables/drivers?

Comment: Is that monitor over 21:9, EG: 32:9? I've heard of issues this one friend keeps having with this resolution, mostly in games. I recommend to you to look for the latest stable nvdia drivers that your g-card can handle. If MSI tells you that this card in specific have bugs, then you should follow them up and wait.

Comment: Yeah, it's 27, I have latest stable Nvidia driver and I invidia suggested me to change my cable and use HDMI instead of DP to locate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh/frame rate being set to a value that is too high might cause flickering
and other artifacts, as the frames might overlap.
This might be an issue if your monitor is of
very high resolution, even at the published value of 144Hz.

Try to reduce the refresh rate, even to very low values, to see if this is indeed
the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if that solves the issue? I would like to have the refresh rate 144Hz. my graphics card supports 144Mz as my monitor.

Comment: If it solves the problem we will know more about the problem.

Comment: Yeah seems that solves the problem but, how can we get 144Hz back?

Comment: It now depends on your monitor, if it has parameters that allow it to work faster. In any case, you might not be able to see the difference between 144Hz and (say) 120Hz. If you now know the problem and have a workaround, you could mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: In your opinion what is that problem? like what I have to do to find out more about that issue. also, I still have guarantee do I have to replace the monitor or graphics card like is it hardware glitch?

Comment: You have a wonderful card, but it might be too good for the monitor. Recommendations are not allowed on this site, but with Nvidia I prefer monitors that support G-Sync, such as Predator.

Comment: So,do you think changing my monitor would solve the issue. I do have MSI Optix G27C do you think I need to replace it?

Comment: I can't say - I don't know MSI. For a high-res monitor, I hope you are putting it on the DisplayPort.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the DP. Till now I don't know what the issue is so I have requested a refund for my current monitor and getting Asus ROG Swift PG248Q G-Sync, what do you think about it?

Comment: Looks very nice and better than your old one.